# Java 8 - Best way to truncate all items of a list starting from a given item

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, iterator, java-stream

Given a list of objects of type Car, what is the most sophisticated way (using Java 8) to truncate a list starting from a certain value?

Example:

```
Class Car {
   String name;
   public Car(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}

List<Car> cars = new ArrayList();
cars.add(new Car("Accord"));
cars.add(new Car("Civic"));
cars.add(new Car("CRV"));
cars.add(new Car("Corolla"));
cars.add(new Car("Camry"));
cars.add(new Car("Forerunner"));

Input:["Accord", "Civic", "CRV", "Corolla", "Camry", "Forerunner"], "Corolla"
Expected Output: ["Camry", "Forerunner"]
```

Comment: on what basis you want to remove ? and have you overriden `equals` ?

Comment: Your use of the English language is very confusing.  Truncate means to remove stuff *after* a given point.  What you are actually trying to do is to remove stuff *before* a given point.

Comment: What if the list has two cars with the name `Corolla`?

Comment: You will have to add hashcode and equals for your Car class in order to find elements in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your requirement is to truncate the list starting **from a certain index** value and return the resulting list.

You can use the inbuilt `list.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` method available for the list interface of Java 8. Refer to the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) for more details.

In your above example the code would look like below,

```
cars.subList(4,6)
```

Note that the **fromIndex is inclusive** while the **toIndex is exclusive**.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like the following?

I deliberately left it simple, i.e. using strings instead of `Car` objects, because the `Car` object is really irrelevant to the task, so this is more general for others to use too.

```java
private static List<String> subListAfter(List<String> values, String startAfter) {
    int idx = values.indexOf(startAfter);
    return (idx == -1 ? Collections.emptyList() : values.subList(idx + 1, values.size()));
}
```

*Test*

```java
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList("Accord", "Civic", "CRV", "Corolla", "Camry", "Forerunner");
System.out.println(subListAfter(wordList, "Corolla"));
```

*Output*

```
[Camry, Forerunner]
```

Answer (score 1):

Fist find the index of the element you are looking for and then create a subList from that index:

```
  List<Car> cars = new ArrayList();
            cars.add(new Car("Accord"));
            cars.add(new Car("Civic"));
            cars.add(new Car("CRV"));
            cars.add(new Car("Corolla"));
            cars.add(new Car("Camry"));
            cars.add(new Car("Forerunner"));
    
            int index = cars.stream()
                             .map(car -> car.name)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList())
                             .indexOf("Corolla");
            List<Car> trimedCarList = cars.subList(index+1,cars.size());
            trimedCarList.forEach(car -> System.out.println(car.name));
```